# Not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

Can any body help me find out, why this link(webRTC example) http://goo.gl/PNMSII not working on firefox? It's working fine on Chrome & Opera but not on firefox.

I've planned to build one photo capturing tool from webcam, but got stuck now.

Comment: what version of FF do you use..update if its old and check again..

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with firefox-33.0

Comment: Can you able to take photo ? I mean, after clicking on 'TAKE PHOTO' link, is your photo showing on the page ?

Comment: Can confirm on Mac OSX Yosemite. FF Version - 32.0.2

Comment: Here is a screenshot link of my firefox, after clicking on TAKE PHOTO link - http://imgur.com/b4gAY70

Comment: I can confirm the same issue on FF 33 on ubuntu...interesting

Comment: Also, tried a different site, and the issue persists(apprtc.appspot.com) seems like a bug

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

```
function validate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      var regex = /[0-9a-fA-F]|\./;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }

}
```